# How to load script conditionally on custom field in wp_postmeta?

Tags: custom-field, errors, wp-enqueue-script

I'm trying to tidy up some of the code that has been doing its job for quite a while. Specifically, I used to load scripts in `header.php` and I'm trying to move that into `functions.php`.

One of the scripts should be loaded only for pages with a certain value in `wp_postmeta`. Precisely, if and only if this table has the value `true` for `meta_key "mathjax"`, the mathjax script should be loaded.

In `header.php` I used

```
function my_init() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        // REGISTER/ENQUEUE OTHER SCRIPTS...
        $mathjax = get_post_meta($post->ID,'mathjax',true);
            if($mathjax == 'y'){
                wp_enqueue_script('mathjax');
            }
    }
}

add_action('init', 'my_init');
```

Now, this code doesn't work in `functions.php` because `$post` is undefined. Can I still move this code into `functions.php` and if so, how can I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**
If you use $post in a function, you have to define it of course:

```
function xyz(){
    global $post;
    //Your code
}
```

**Initial answer, might help others:**
It appears to me, you do not use it inside an action or if so, you use it to early. It should work inside the 'init' action. So you could do something like

```
<?php
add_action( 'init', 'enqueue_conditionally' );
function enqueue_conditionally(){
    $mathjax = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(),'mathjax',true);
    if($mathjax == 'y'){
        wp_enqueue_script('mathjax');
    }
}
?>
```

Ref.: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init

Comment: sorry, I actually do use it in a function, followed by `add_action` but those lines didn't seem relevant to me. Please give me a few minutes to try and get your example running before I get back on that, ok?

Comment: the good news is that I'm no longer getting an error. However, the script doesn't load with the `if` condition around it (but it does load after commenting out the `if` part). I inspected the DB whether `mathjax` is set properly and it is... Any idea what may cause that?

Comment: updated my answer according to your new info.